# Create Pop-Up Box with Custom Field Content Inside the Loop

Tags: custom-field, query

I tried this using ThickBox first, then tried using some code I had that worked on another website... Total failure.

**The Goal:**
I have a custom post type (product) with a ton of custom fields.
I also have a page that says "display all of these custom fields, and for each one show custom fields X, Y, and Z."
So far so good.

Where it goes wonky is when I try to insert a popup or a collapsible element for one of the fields (`sample_script`).

No matter what I try, whatever ends up working ONLY shows the `sample_script` value from the first item on the page/inside of the loop. So if you click on a link that should trigger a popup/hidden accordion that displays the contents of `sample_script`, you're ONLY getting the `sample_script` value off of the first one, not whatever other custom post you're looking at.

**What I have Right Now:**
This is the current code I'm working with that's trying to utilize `animatedcollapse.js`:

```
    <?php query_posts( array(
'post_type' =>'product',
'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
 'showposts' => 9999999,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy'  => 'Group',
        'field'     => 'slug',
        'terms'     => array( 'books','video' ),
        'operator'  => 'NOT IN',
    ),
)
    ) ); ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div style="width:100%; display:block; text-align:center">
          <?php if( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'highspeed_daytime_mp3_code', true) ) { ?>
          <div class="project-floater">
            <center>
              <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><img class="thumb" src="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'product_cover', true ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="142" /></a><br />
              <a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.show('script-sample')">What's On the Recording?</a>
              <div id="script-sample" style="display:none; float:none">
                <div style="width:70px; padding-left:10px; float:right"><a href="javascript:animatedcollapse.hide('script-sample')"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/btn_close_button.png" alt="Close"></a></div>
                <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sample_script', true); ?></div>
              <div align="center"><a href="http://www.ewebcart.com/cgi-bin/cart.pl?merchant=2465&add=01&item_id=<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'highspeed_daytime_mp3_code', true ); ?>" target="_self"><img src="images/homebuyplatinum.gif" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width="75" height="30" border="0"></a></div>
              </a>
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Anybody super smart and excited to help a dummy?  I'm drowning over here!  I just need to hide the sample script for each item until the user clicks on it, then it either expands or pops up (I don't care which, I just need the stuff to show).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not assigning a unique ID to each popup element. HTML element IDs should be unique, and each time you call `animatedcollapse.show( 'script-sample' )` it will target the first element with the id "script-sample". What you could do is assign a unique ID to each popup element by using the post IDs:

```
<div id="script-sample-<?php the_ID(); ?>" [..]
```

You could target that particular element by using

```
animatedcollapse.show( 'script-sample-<?php the_ID(); ?>' )
```

By the way, you probably shouldn't be using `query_posts`, it's quite horrible and [there are better alternatives](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).